# how to monitor that the fields have changed and get oldvalues and new values as well

Tags: angularjs

In my project i have implemented a web page in angularjs. When i go for the edit page and changes values of some fields,after that i click save button. On clicking the save button i want to get the fieldName in which change occur, old value & new value of the fields and send it to node.js.

i have tried but not working.

```
     function auditChecker(oldObj,newObj,fn){
        var newVal={};
        var data=[];
        for (var key in newObj) {
        if(newObj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        for(var key1 in oldObj){
            if(oldObj.hasOwnProperty(key1)){
                if(oldObj[key1]!=newObj[key]){
                    newVal.fieldName = 'asdf';
                    newVal.oldval = oldObj[key];
                    newVal.newval = newObj[key];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
data.push(newVal);
fn(data);
```

}

is there any quick way to do this. I need to write one funtion that works on different edit function.

Answer (score 0):

### You can use watch to get the old and new value.

For example,

```
$scope.$watch('yourScopeVariable', function (newValue, oldValue) {

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Above doesn't look like an Angular approach to me! But to get this done with Angular approach you should try below

```js
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('someValue', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log('oldValue=' + oldValue);
        console.log('newValue=' + newValue);
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="exampleab" ng-model="someValue"  >
```

Fiddle here http://fiddle.jshell.net/43onhmya/1/

Comment: i have multiple fields. So, using $watch leads more code. i.e i have to watch each fields. For that i was trying to write once use anywhwere concept. But still i'm not getting that. and each fieldname, oldvalue,newvalue should be in an object

Comment: If you have multiple fields in form, you can iterate them in loop and add watch on each key

Comment: my fields contains both input and select fields.can you put  some sample code here. it would be better to know more

Comment: the above function is written pure js code. and i send the result to angular controler from that i send it to node server.